# Cannot open shared ACCESS file

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, error-handling, vba

To install a simple software solution, shared access database. I had to press on a .accde file in a shared folder. Normally the first time someone doing this it will work. Now im receiving errors. The shared access database is linked with a sql server.

When opening it the following errors appear. After the Errors I see the the file but is it stuck/freezed, not working.

First Error Screen.

```
Error 3027:

Cannot update. Database or object is read-only.

Originated in DAO.TableDef

Occurred 29-5-2015 9:34:04
```

Second Error Screen:

```
The expression On load you entered as the event property setting produced the following error: The operation on the The operation on the | object failed object failed.

* The expression may not result in the name of a macro, the name of a user defined function, or [Event Procedure].
* There may have been an error evaluating the function, event, or macro.

[Open Help Window]
This error occurs when an event has failed to run because the location of the logic for the event cannot be evaluated. For example, if the OnOpen property of a form is set to =[Field], this error occurs because a macro or event name is expected to run when the event occurs.
```

Is it possible that all the current users of the access database has to shut down the program. Cause in the icon of the file it seems locked. This icon:

[image: icon]

Edit:

The software is made by a 3rd party. It uses Access as a user interface where you interact with a sql server. Someone who want to use the software need to open this .accde file when opening it for the first time. After that a shortcut will appear on the desktop.

Comment: Each user should have their own front-end.

Comment: how do you access the file?

Comment: The second Icon that appears on the desktop is a temporary file, similar to what's created when you open an excel sheet. If a user is forced to close access it will remain. You should be able to just delete the file, then reopen access normally.